# 3DS Max 2017 Python API - Load Texture from Disk, Apply to Material

Tags: python, 3dsmax

I am trying to load a Targa image from disk and apply it as the diffuse map on a node using the Python API for 3DS Max 2017.

I am able to create a material and apply the material to the node.  In addition, I can create bitmap textures.  However, I am not sure how to apply a material with the texture onto the node.

Here is some example code.

```
bitmapTex = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateDefaultBitmapTex()
bitmapTex.SetMapName(r'The full path to my image.')
bitmapTex.ReloadBitmapAndUpdate()

material = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateDefaultStdMat()

#
# Not really sure how to combine the texture and the material.
# Or if the 'bitmapTex' is somehow castable to a material
# to apply to the node directly.

myNode.Material = material
```

Any help or information would be appreciated.